# Control log axis size/length using PROC GPLOT in SAS

Tags: plot, sas, scatter-plot

I'm trying to produce a 'square' scatter plot, where both axes are on a log (base 10) scale. The basic code is:

```
goptions reset=all device=activex;

axis1 logbase=10 length=15cm;
axis2 logbase=10 length=15cm;
symbol color=bigb value=circle height=0.5;

proc gplot data=source uniform;
    title 'blah blah';
    plot var1*var2 / haxis=axis1 vaxis=axis2;
    where type = 'chosen';
    run;
quit;
```

var1 contains values that that span >0 to 1,000,000. var2 contains values that span >0 to 10,000,000.

I want both axis to go to 10,000,000 whilst maintaining the log scale. I've tried everything but no luck. I thought the order= option in the axis statement would help,

```
axis1 logbase=10 length=15cm order=(1 to 10000000);
```

but I kept getting warnings in the log that the list exceeds some maximum value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions for you.

1) When using LOGBASE=10 on the AXIS statement, you need to specify the actual values instead of FROM and TO.  Like this:

```
axis1 logbase=10 length=10cm order=(1 10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000 10000000);
```

2) I often have a problem with large numbers on the axis and will create a custom format to display numbers as powers of 10 for read-ability on the graph.  Then apply this format to VAR1 and VAR2 in the PROC GPLOT.

```
proc format;
    value power
        1 = '10^0'
        10 = '10^1'
        100 = '10^2'
        1000 = '10^3'
        10000 = '10^4'
        100000 = '10^5'
        1000000 = '10^6'
        10000000 = '10^7'
    ;
run;
```

3) When I tried to run your code, the y-axis would be cutoff at the top of the graph.  And I think it's because of the driver you chose.  I investigated the ACTIVEX driver by doing:

```
proc gdevice  c=sashelp.devices ;
  list _all_;
run;
```

When the GDEVICE window comes up, type 'S' in front of ACTIVEX.  This will bring up details about this particular driver.  According to the details, ACTIVEX has XMAX=8.333in (or 18.33cm) and YMAX=6.25in (or 13.75cm).  So that is why the the y-axis was cutting off.  Consider changing the LENGTH option on the AXIS statement to maybe 10cm or smaller.

Hope this helps!